# Set Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following cardinalities ordered from smallest to greatest

- $|\varnothing|$
- $|A - B|$
- $|A ⊕ B|$

But I am stuck between these two:

$|A| + |B|$ and $|A \cup B|$

Are these two equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if $A \cap B$ is nonempty. For instance, let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$. Then $|A|+|B|=4$, while $|A\cup B| = |\{1,2,3\}|=3$.

Answer (score 1):

also $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|- |A \cap B|$  if $ A \cap B $ is non-empty